# Android webview somtime stop load image in loading

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using `WebView` in view holder with `RigidWebView` and option is here (layout height is **wrap_content**)

https://github.com/jisung/RigidWebView

```kotlin
itemView.webViewPost.settings.apply {
    javaScriptEnabled = true
    databaseEnabled = true
    setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    domStorageEnabled = true
    builtInZoomControls = false
    setSupportMultipleWindows(false)
    setSupportZoom(false)
    blockNetworkImage = false
    allowFileAccess = true
    loadWithOverviewMode = true
    loadsImagesAutomatically = true
    setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
    loadWithOverviewMode = true
}

itemView.webViewPost.apply {
    isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
    isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
}
```

- Hardware acceleration is activated in `AndroidManifest.xml`

I am using `WebView` by calling `webView.loadData(html)` directly.

**Problem**

I have source like this. (4 images)

```html
<img src="111" />
<img src="111" />
<img src="111" />
<img src="111" />
```

Rendering mostly fine. but sometimes render like this.

(like internet disconnected)

-> Third image is not loaded completely and Fourth image is not loaded, and stop rendering

[image: screenshot]

When retry (call loadData again), almost fine.

But this situation is not good for users.

How can I avoid this rendering failed on first situation?

Comment: any specific reason to use webview to load image here? use glide over there instead and load url using that.

Comment: server returns html source. I have no choice... @Radhey

Comment: what do you see if you try remote debugging in chrome and see what is happening in network tab?